# Eclipse is not include a persistence.xml in an EJB project

Tags: eclipse, jpa, ejb

I have createdd an EJB project for writing Entites,DAO and Facade classes. But There is no any persistence.xml file in my project. Otherwise I must create a persistence.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will only include a `persistence.xml` file if you add the JPA facet to the project. Right-click the EJB project, go to "Project Facets" and check the box next to "JPA".

Comment: now I am getting connection could not be allocated because  SSL. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the `Dynamic Web Module 3.0` facet in your project.

Either that, or add it manually. It's doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Should be the JPA facet, not the Dynamic Web Module one. Plus, while it doesn't make a difference in runtime, it makes a difference in development time as the Eclipse JPA plugins become activated.

Comment: @Isaac At first, I wasn't sure whether it's the JPA facet or the DWM. Good to know, thank you.